# I accidentally sold all of my Bitcoin with a limit order because I had never done one before

Tags: cryptocurrency, cost-basis, mistakes

I decided to try a limit order to sell all of my Bitcoin if it dropped to a low level. This was my first time trying a limit order. I didn't understand that it would sell at my low asking price, which was about 30,000 OR BETTER. Well better was about 70,000. So it instantly sold all of my Bitcoin at 70,000. I realized I really hadn't lost much of anything unless I waited and had to buy it for more. And of course bitcoin has been expected to go way up. So I kind of freaked out and immediately bought it back at about the same price. Now I'm not concerned about the tax implications. What I'm concerned about is that my cost basis before the trade was about 52,000, and so now instead of holding Bitcoin at that price, I now was holding it at the price of 70,000. I understand. I did not lose anything on the sale, but by doing this won't I earn less future profit because my cost basis is no longer 50,000, but 70,000? Did I just lose $20,000?

Comment: Tax laws differ by country. In the US, you pay tax on capital gains in the year you made the transaction, but you can only deduct up to $3K of loss per year (unless you have other capital gains to offset from). So you'll end up paying the taxes on the $18K per coin gain now, and then when you sell at 52K, you'll have $18K/coin loss that may take you centuries to deduct if you had a lot of these coins.

Answer (score 7):

If the cost basis was $52,000 a coin and you sold it for $70,000 a coin that means your tax agency will be expecting you to pay taxes on the $18,000 a coin in gains. You will have to check the appropriate tax law for your jurisdiction to know how much you will have to pay in tax.

The good news is that when you sell your new coins the gain or loss will be calculated from the 70,000 per coin level.

The bad news is that you may impact some other parts of your finical picture if the number of coins sold is large; if it was only a small fraction of a coin the total impact could be very small.